# Style for continued multi-line f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.6

Do any popular Python style guides express a preference between:

```
x = (f'One plus one is '
     f'equal to {1+1}')
```

and:

```
x = ('One plus one is '
     f'equal to {1+1}')
```

Does it make sense to omit the `f` prefix for lines that don't involve interpolation? Should it be included for consistency?

Comment: Nice phrasing. I was about to vote to close as opinion based but then read carefully +1.

Comment: I'd say only use the prefix for the strings where you need to. It looks cleaner.

Comment: @ChristianDean. Why? I feel like they line up nicer the other way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And thus we see why you were about to flag it as opinion based. ;-)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well I mean, it was just my opinion :-) (which is why I posted it as a comment). It really can't offer an objective reason. It just makes more sense to me to use the prefix only on the strings that need it. Using on every string just seems like overkill.

Comment: A related question is whether an f-string with no  formats generates the same instructions as a literal or an f-string.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, it does. Ask the question and I'll show you. :-)

Comment: @Mad Physicist True, but it also falsely pretends there is an expression.

Comment: @Turn Yep, I just looked at it. Python seems to ignore the prefix if its not used.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Here's an example: https://repl.it/repls/ConstantWretchedKilldeer. In the end, I guess it doesn't really make a difference whether you choose to use the `f` prefix superfluously, or not.

Comment: Regularly encountered this same trivial dilemma in my test suite.  It's annoying either way..  :(

Comment: @ayhan Yep, sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: @ChristianDean Don't you actually want to compare f'1' and '1'?

Comment: For consistency reasons one could argue to use `f` for every line, like you would have to write `x = (b"hello"
     b"world") for bytes.

Comment: @Darkonaut But for bytes, that’s because you cannot mix those with strings… You should rather compare constant f-strings with raw string literals.

Comment: Not an answer, but: I've settled on putting the prefix on every line.  It's easier on the eyes, and if you come back to add in a variable later you needn't remember to add the prefix as well (it's really easy to forget).

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the generated byte code for each of those two options, you will see that this both results in the same set of operations:

```
>>> dis.dis("""f'One plus one is ' f'equal to {1+1}'""")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('One plus one is equal to ')
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 BUILD_STRING             2
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("""'One plus one is ' f'equal to {1+1}'""")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('One plus one is equal to ')
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 BUILD_STRING             2
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

So for Python, this both does exactly the same thing: The string is being concatenated at compile-time, and the whole string is being evaluated as a format string.

Note though that as per [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#concatenating-strings), f-strings are actually concatenated at run-time, to make sure that every format expression is evaluated independently:

> Adjacent f-strings and regular strings are concatenated. Regular strings are concatenated at compile time, and f-strings are concatenated at run time.

That is why the following example will generate two `FORMAT_VALUE` opcodes:

```
>>> dis.dis("""f'{2+2}' f'{3+3}'""")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              2 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              6 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              8 BUILD_STRING             2
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

This will not have an effect for f-strings that don’t actually contain any format placeholders though. Those will still be concatenated at compile-time:

```
>>> dis.dis("""f'foo' f'bar'""")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('foobar')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

So you can just include the `f` prefix for constant strings anyway and when they don’t contain a format expression, they won’t end up being handled as format strings.

So in your particular case, since there is no functional difference and both options are compiled to the same thing, that leaves this as a pure style choice which everyone has to answer for themselves.

If you are looking at existing style guides, chances are that they are not covering f-strings yet. But then, you could use the same guideline as for raw strings, although I personally don’t expect style guides to really cover that area much. Just choose what looks best, is readable, and what makes most sense to you. After all, continued strings are not really *that* common (and you are more likely to have triple-quotes for longer strings).

Comment: This answered my other question, which is whether f-strings get concatenated or not. +1

Comment: "continued strings are not really that common"

I find I pretty frequently run into them writing error messages.